# How can i create common viewmodelfactory with repository in kotlin android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I want to create single viewmodelfactory for multiple viewmodels in kotlin android. how can i achieve this ?

```
class AppViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LoginViewModel::class.java)) {
            return LoginViewModel(
                loginRepository = LoginRepository(
                    dataSource = LoginDataSource()
                )
            ) as T
        }

        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(UserViewModel::class.java)) {
            return UserViewModel(
                userRepository = UserRepository(
                    dataSource = UserDataSource()
                )
            ) as T
        }

        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(TransactionViewModel::class.java)) {
            return TransactionViewModel(
                transactionRepository = TransactionRepository(
                    dataSource = TransactionDataSource()
                )
            ) as T
        }
        
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

as in above code i need to write multiple viewmodels name like loginviewmodel, userviewmodel and transactionviewmodel. how can i reduce the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten it with single expression format, a when statement, and you probably don't need to name properties in the constructors:

```
class AppViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = when(modelClass){
        LoginViewModel::class.java -> LoginViewModel(LoginRepository(LoginDataSource()))
        UserViewModel::class.java -> UserViewModel(UserRepository(UserDataSource()))
        TransactionViewModel::class.java -> TransactionViewModel(TransactionRepository(TransactionDataSource()))
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    } as T
}
```

Comment: The greatest problem with this is that if we have 50 or more ViewModels in a project, we could potentially end up converting this function into a monstrosity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use create factory kotlin extension to create ViewModel factories at run time.

**Extension**

```
fun <T : ViewModel> T.createFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    val viewModel = this
    return object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModel as T
    }
}
```

**How to use it**

```
private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
private fun initLoginViewModel() {
      val factory = LoginViewModel(LoginDataSource()).createFactory()
      loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to pass LoginDataSource() object as per your constructor of your LoginViewModel.  I have changed the code according to it.

Comment: its not good idea in mvvm to use  repository in view class....

Comment: We are not using it, we are only initializing it.  As good practice it should come through dependency injection, but for now, you can initialize in view. not a big issue. It doesn't violate the rule of MVVM

Comment: ViewModel always initializes through view because it needs a lifecycle. For initializes, we need to pass mandatory objects to the ViewModel constructor

Comment: I don’t think this is a good idea. The point of a factory is that it only instantiates the ViewModel when it can’t reuse an existing instance. This has you preemptively instantiate a ViewModel and repository regardless of whether they will be used.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using following dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1")
```

and then try creating the view model instance

```
val viewModel:CoinListViewModel  by viewModels()
```